# How to assign inventory group alias to a variable?

Tags: ansible

I have this Ansible inventory file:

```
[fileservers]
fs01.example.com   ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.1    ip_addr=192.168.1.1

[dbservers]
db01.example.com   ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.2    ip_addr=192.168.1.2

[webservers]
web01.example.com   ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.3    ip_addr=192.168.1.3

[cmsservers]
cms01.example.com   ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.4    ip_addr=192.168.1.4
```

What I want to do is be able to set some facts that contain the host aliases when I run this playbook on my web01.example.com server:

```
- name: create alias facts
  set_fact:
    file_server_alias: hostvars[{{ inventory_hostname }}]['groups']['fileservers'][0]  # should get string 'fs01.example.com'
    db_server_alias: hostvars[{{ inventory_hostname }}]['groups']['dbservers'][0]      # should get string 'db01.example.com'
    cms_server_alias: hostvars[{{ inventory_hostname }}]['groups']['cmsservers'][0]    # should get string 'cms01.example.com'
```

However, when I do the above, file_server_alias just gets set to 'hostvars[{{ inventory_hostname }}]['groups']['fileservers'][0]', and so on.  Is there any way to assign these inventory group aliases to variables?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the whole assigned expression inside the moustaches. This example is working for me in ansible-playbook 2.5.1 and Python 2.7

```
---
- hosts: fileservers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
        - name: create alias facts
          set_fact:
            file_server_alias: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['groups']['fileservers'][0] }}" # should get string 'fs01.example.com'
            db_server_alias: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['groups']['dbservers'][0] }}"      # should get string 'db01.example.com'
            cms_server_alias: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['groups']['cmsservers'][0] }}"    # should get string 'cms01.example.com'
        - name: debug
          debug:
            msg: "{{ file_server_alias }} {{ db_server_alias }} {{ cms_server_alias }}"
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml 

PLAY [fileservers] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [create alias facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [fs01.example.com]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [fs01.example.com] => {
    "msg": "fs01.example.com db01.example.com cms01.example.com"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fs01.example.com           : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```